# Run SSIS Package Without SQL Server Integration Services

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-2016, ssis-2016

Can we run SSIS Package without integration services? If Yes then what are the steps? If No then what is the minimum requirement.

The problem statement is as follow:

I am using SQL Azure database to store the data. I also have Azure VM from which I need to schedule SSIS Packages. In this Azure VM we don't have Integration Services Installed. My approach is to schedule the SSIS package using batch file in windows scheduler.

I have gone through various threads and posts regarding this but didn't get the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot run a SSIS package *(.dtsx)* without installing the SQL Server integration Services. The minimum requirements are the SSIS client tools and the DTEXEC utility so you must install the Integration Services shared feature from the SQL Server install media.

**References**

- [Run SSIS package in a machine without Sql Server](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2933489a-0684-409a-b0ac-3dc781a3e58e/run-ssis-package-in-a-machine-without-sql-server?forum=sqlintegrationservices)
- [Ways to execute SSIS package](http://www.bigator.com/2012/03/11/ways-to-execute-ssis-package/)
- [Running an SSIS package without the SSIS service installed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5158/running-an-ssis-package-without-the-ssis-service-installed)
- https://www.sqlshack.com/ways-use-execute-sql-server-integration-services-packages/

Comment: Thanks Hadi for the comment. I figure out I need Integration services. I tried running the the package using batch file and it gives me an error of system variable not found and I am using system variable in my code. Though I found some "dtexec" in server. I dont know how it come there  but that is not sufficient to run the packages.

Comment: Make sure that the name of system variable you used is typed correctly. It is case sensitive https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-variables

Comment: It is working fine in SSDT and on the machine where the Integration services are installed. Tried using the batch file and cmd both.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, you can avoid a full install of SQL server if you use SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT).  Try this link:
You can install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) without installing SQL Server by itself, and then you can use integration services. Try this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017